# How do I handle this data type

Tags: haskell

I have to organize a list of numbers in this data type based on the numbers operator (positive or negative) or if the number is zero. But I'm not sure how to do this.

```
data Numbers
  = Numbers{
      pos  :: [Int]
    , neg  :: [Int]
    , nul  :: [Int]
    } deriving Show
```

That's the function I thought of doing, only it's not complete. How would I do the Add to the _ List part?

```
numList :: [Int] -> Numbers
numList [] = []
numList ((x:xs)
 |x == 0    = add-to-the-nul-list-and : numList xs
 |x > 0     = add-to-the-pos-list-and : numList xs
 |otherwise = add-to-the-neg-list-and : numList xs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this:

- Bind the recursive result locally, then put the constructor back together with one of the fields modified.

  ```
  numList (x:xs)
    | x==0       = Numbers posxs negxs (x:nulxs)
    | x>0        = Numbers (x:posxs) negxs nulxs
    | otherwise  = Numbers posxs (x:negxs) nulxs
   where Numbers posxs negxs nulxs = numList xs
  ```
- Compute it in a local binding and use record update syntax.

  ```
  numList (x:xs)
    | x==0       = nums_xs{ nul = x : nul nums_xs }
    | x>0        = nums_xs{ pos = x : pos nums_xs }
    | otherwise  = nums_xs{ neg = x : neg nums_xs }
   where nums_xs = numList xs
  ```
- Use [`lens`es](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) to apply an update to a specific record field. This is most nicely done by modifying the data definition a bit:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

  import Control.Lens

  data Numbers = Numbers{
     _pos  :: [Int]
   , _neg  :: [Int]
   , _nul  :: [Int]
   } deriving Show
  makeLenses ''Numbers
  ```

  Then

  ```
  numList (x:xs)
    | x==0       = nums_xs & nul %~ (x:)
    | x>0        = nums_xs & pos %~ (x:)
    | otherwise  = nums_xs & neg %~ (x:)
   where nums_xs = numList xs
  ```

  In this form, you can also remove the code duplications, your entire function can be written

  ```
  numList [] = Numbers [] [] []
  numList (x:xs) = numList xs
    & ( case compare x 0 of
         EQ -> nul
         LT -> neg
         GT -> pos
      ) %~ (x:)
  ```

  or

  ```
  numList = foldr categorise $ Numbers [] [] []
   where categorise x
          | x==0       = nul %~ (x:)
          | x>0        = pos %~ (x:)
          | otherwise  = neg %~ (x:)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

An approach I like is to observe that your type has a monoidal structure. If you write out the instances for that structure, you can use `foldMap` to do the list manipulation for you.

```
instance Monoid Numbers where
  mempty = Numbers [] [] []

instance Semigroup Numbers where
  (Numbers lpos lneg lnul) <> (Numbers rpos rneg rnul) =
    Numbers (lpos <> rpos) (lneg <> rneg) (lnul <> rnul)

numList :: [Int] -> Numbers
numList = foldMap categorize
  where categorize x = case compare x 0 of
                            GT -> Numbers [x] [] []
                            LT -> Numbers [] [x] []
                            EQ -> Numbers [] [] [x]
```

Obviously this is more code than just doing the single task before you, but it's generally helpful to write out instances for classes your type could participate in. Having this Monoid instance will simplify other future tasks as well.