# Newline is printing \n rather than the usual

Tags: haskell

This is a "continuation" from this post: [How do I handle this data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68532330/how-do-i-handle-this-data-type)

So now I have to print a "table" of numbers according to Numbers type in this format:

Positive Numbers:

1

4

16

Negative Numbers:

-3

-69

Null Numbers:

0

0

So I made this function:

```
printNum :: Numbers -> String
printNum (Numbers po ne nn)=  "Positive Numbers: \n " ++ numP po ++
                              " \n Negative Numbers: \n " ++ numN ne ++
                              " \n Null Numbers: \n " ++ numZ nn
  where
      numP (p:ps) = show p ++ " \n " ++ numP ps
      numP [] = []
      numN (n:ns) = show n ++ " \n " ++ numN ns
      numN [] = []
      numZ (z:zs) = show z ++ " \n " ++ numZ zs
      numZ [] = []
```

But the function is printing like this:
"Positive Numbers: \n 1 \n 4 \n 16 \n  \n Negative Numbers: \n -3 \n -69 \n  \n Null Numbers: \n 0 \n 0 \n "

Comment: Please share your `main`, or the place where you *print* the outcome of `printNum`.

Comment: If you call a function in GHCi it prints the result using the 'Show' instance. For strings this gives the escaped version of the string. Try using 'putStrLn' to output the result.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't have a main yet, here's how I'm doing it on the GHCi:                           > let numex = numList [1,-3,4,0,-69,0,8]
> printNum numex

Comment: @CarlosMelo: it will print the string as a string literal, if you use `putStrLn (printNum numex)`, it will *print* the *content* of the string.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Yes I'm using the GHCi. I tried using putStrLn but it gave me an error. How would you implement it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This worked! But how do I implement it on the printNum function?

Comment: @CarlosMelo: change the output type to `IO ()`, and work with `putStrLn` in the definition of your `printNum` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GHCi, if you enter an expresssion it will evaluate that expression, and if the outcome type is not *unit* (`()`), it will `print` to use `show` to present the result of that expression. For a `String`, it will thus write a `String` *literal* to present this.

You can work with [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) to print the *content* of the string, not as a string literal, so:

```
putStrLn (printNum numex)
```

Comment: Ahh I understand it now, I wanted to use putStrLn but then I would have to chage my function to printNum :: Numbers -> IO ()